# Ошибка CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»

Tags: javascript

Хочу отправить запрос, но получаю 403 код

```
const API_KEY = "my_api_key";

fetch("https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/capital/config/getall", {
  headers: {
    "X-MBX-APIKEY": API_KEY,
  },
})
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });
```

В качестве сервера использую `webpack-dev-server`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
    },
  },
};
```

Ответ сервера
[image: Ответ сервера]

Заголовки сервера
[image: Заголовки запроса]

Заголовки ответа
[image: Заголовки ответа]

Comment: 403 код - ошибка доступа. что возвращается в теле ответа?

Comment: @sterx, "Тело ответа недоступно для сценариев (Причина: CORS Missing Allow Origin)"

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev в инструментах разработчика посмотрите

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я от туда и взял

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev, смотри заголовки а не "ответ"

Comment: запрос OPTIONS получает вышеуказанные заголовки от сервера?

Comment: тебе нужно смотреть заголовки ответа. Добавь в вопрос саму ошибку полностью

Comment: CORS это способ защиты выполняемый на веб сервере/файрволе. Типо прероутинг. Гугл говорит что у них валидация API идёт на уровне CORS. Проверьте свой API ключ. Или напишите сюда какой-нибудь тестовый